# Return a variable text string to an adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a large spreadsheet.

Some of the cells contain order numbers in cells containing text.

The order number is located in various positions within the cell. I am trying to return the order number (alone) in the cell adjacent to the cell containing the order number as part of the text.

Comment: it is impossible to help without some examples of order numbers and of how they might be embedded. What is the format of an order number? What other text may be in the embedding cell?

Comment: Hi the order numbers start IT0. How can I pull out the IT0 Cell?          Cell A2 AS - IT04697 4 additional Nice single user/web client licences 
Cell A3 Supply of H/W for Contact Centre IT02161
Cell A4 "Supply of H/W for Contact Centre IT02185 Delivered price.
Cell A5 Supply for Contact Centre IT02161

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can go through this... http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `FIND` function to locate the order number, and `MIDB` to extract a substring: set `B2` to:

```
=MIDB(A2,FIND("IT0",A2),7)
```

Then propagate this down the rest of the column.

I have tested it with your sample cells. It will become a lot more complex if your order numbers are not of fixed length, and you will need to specify the order number format exactly. There will also be a problem if the string `IT0` occurs in the text before the order number itself, and again you will need a precise ON format definition.

Comment: You should mark it as solved, so that others can easily see that there is a solution.